# Read a .txt file in Python avoiding special characters to replace original characters inside the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, special-characters

I want to know how can I read a .txt file in a way that special characters don't overwrite the contents in my .txt file so that I can retain the original file content

I am using the following lines of code:

```
with open('D:/nap31.txt') as gh:
    line = True
    while line:
        line = gh.readline()
```

Sample content from nap31.txt file:

```
Teda Production Site Oranienburg Lehnitzstr. 70 – 98 16515 Oranienburg France packaging

Zene AB Gärtunavägen SE-151 85 Södertälje SWEDEN Testing
```

After opening the file and reading it using the above code, content becomes:

```
Teda Production Site Oranienburg Lehnitzstr. 70 â€“ 98 16515 Oranienburg France packaging

ï»¿Zene AB GÃ¤rtunavÃ¤gen SE-151 85 SÃ¶dertÃ¤lje SWEDEN Testing
```

So  â€“ is replacing '-' in my file and likewise other special characters are replacing other contents. Can someone help me solve this

Comment: Use the correct encoding to open your file:   [https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a file in Python the default encoding is ANSI which won't support these particular characters. Therefore you need to change the encoding to `utf-8`. To do this simply change your code to this:

```
with open('D:/nap31.txt', encoding='utf-8') as gh:
    line = True
    while line:
        line = gh.readline()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was using encoding='utf8' and hence wasn't able to solve it